# Having error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0”

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React btw, I've been trying to read my test.json file which is located in :

> src/data/test.json

My app.js is written as such :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

var HotelData = require('../data/test.json')

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  getDatafromHotel(){
    fetch(HotelData)
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((findresponse) => {
      console.log(findresponse.data);
      this.setState({data: findresponse.data})
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getDatafromHotel();
  }



  render() {
    return(
      <div className="body">
        <div className="container">
        {this.state.HotelData.map((hotel) => (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-1">
            {hotel.roomTypeLabel}
            </div>
            <div className="col-2">
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is there any way that I could read test.json file rather than the index.html in the public folder?

test.json file : https://api.myjson.com/bins/16ocrc

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `require` to import JSON files like you would for javascript ones. Take a look at the `fetch` api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

As for the code you need to change, it would be:

```
getDatafromHotel(){
fetch("../data/test.json")
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((findresponse) => {
        console.log(findresponse.data);
        this.setState({data: findresponse.data})
    })
```

Lastly, you need to remove the `require` statement.

Comment: You can actually use `require` to load JSON files. OP is already using `fetch`, just using it wrong.

Comment: What should i use other than `fetch`?

Comment: You should be using `fetch`. The first parameter of the method needs to be a string (to the url).

Answer (score 0):

the line:

```
var HotelData = require('../data/test.json';
```

should be:

```
var HotelData = '../data/test.json';
```

assuming that location is correct and not a `404`.

Comment: @JohnStefan this hints for `404`. try open open the file in a web-browser... the absolute `URL` should also work. it could as well as be `../../data/test.json` ...depending where it actually is located, _relative to the script referencing it_.